# How to format date and time in hbase?

Tags: datetime, datepicker, hbase

I am getting string result in my date and time. I want to know in which format it is coming.

String:

2015-08-14T22:26:41.9975398Z

Format tried:

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sTZD
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: None of tried format worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was `IsoString` just read this docs : [isostring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) . :)